# Как добавить заголовок между woocommerce форм?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Нужно добавить заголовок между woocommerce формами(на скрине - вместо карсной линии должен быть заголовок) на странице "Checkout". Подскажите, как это сделать? Скрин файлов я тоже прикрепил.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно отредактировать файл woocommerce/checkout/form-billing.php

Найти фрагмент вывода полей и скорректировать его

Например, так

```
<?php
        $fields = $checkout->get_checkout_fields( 'billing' );

        foreach ( $fields as $key => $field ) {
          
            if ($key == 'billing_address_1') {
                echo 'Ваш заголовок';
            }
          
            woocommerce_form_field( $key, $field, $checkout->get_value( $key ) );
        }
?>
```